# How can I get historical prices of Yahoo! Finance from Java?

Tags: java

I need to obtain Yahoo! Finance historical prices in the csv format like in the link here: [Click here for IBM historical prices in Yahoo! Finance](https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=IBM) By specifying the company name for the stock such as IBM or AAPL for apple, how can I obtain the CSV format spreadsheet present as a button named "download to spreadsheet" in the above link?

Comment: This is not a coding platform. Please show us what you have and what problem you have.

Comment: I'm finding trouble finding where to start in the coding part here. I mean, I couldn't find any API for this, so I'm asking if there is any other way to obtain it? Any tutorial towards it would be helpful, I'd code it myself, not looking for a coding platform, just help to start coding towards how to download the spreadsheet data if I know which company data I want. For ex, IBM

Comment: Sorry, if this may sound rude, but i found an api within 10 seconds google. Please note, that this is not a page for dumping google search querys. This is also why your question is heavily down voted.

Comment: Could you please provide me the link of the api? Maybe it's the keywords I searched that was the problem to my own down voting. Anyway, the api link would be heavily appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = new java.net.URL(historicURL + "?s=" + symbol.getCode()
                               + "&d=" + d + "&e=" + e + "&f=" + f + "&g="
                               + g +"&a=" + a + "&b=" + b + "&c=" + c
                               + "&ignore=.csv");
```

Using this link provides the answer to download it.

```
 String a = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(
            new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(start)) - 1);
    /* b - Day number, eg, 1 for the first of the month. */
    String b = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(
            new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(start)));
    /* c - Year. */
    String c = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(
            new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(start)));
    /* d - Month number, starting with 0 for January. */
    String d = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(
            new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(end)) - 1);
    /* e - Day number, eg, 1 for the first of the month. */
    String e = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(
            new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(end)));
    /* f - Year. */
    String f = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(
            new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(end)));
```

Note, month number begins with a 0.